# Could a regular expression be used to find text between pairs of delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, text-parsing

I need to parse an email template for custom variables that occur between pairs of dollar signs, e.g:

```
$foo$bar$baz$foo$bar$baz$wtf
```

So I would want to start by extracting 'foo' above, since it comes between the first pair (1st and 2nd) of dollar signs.  And then skip 'bar' but extract 'baz' as it comes between the next pair (3rd and 4th) of dollar signs.

I was able to accomplish this with `split` and `filter` as below, but am wondering, if there's a way to accomplish the same with a regular expression instead?  I presume some sort of formal parser, recursive or otherwise, could be used, but that would seem like overkill in my opinion

```
const body = "$foo$bar$baz$foo$bar$baz$wtf";
let delimitedSegments = body.split('$');

if (delimitedSegments.length % 2 === 0) {
  // discard last segment when length is even since it won't be followed by the delimiter
  delimitedSegments.pop();
}

const alternatingDelimitedValues = delimitedSegments.filter((segment, index) => {
  return index % 2;
});
console.log(alternatingDelimitedValues);
```

OUTPUT: [ 'foo', 'baz', 'bar' ]

Code also at: https://repl.it/@dexygen/findTextBetweenDollarSignDelimiterPairs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match the delimiter twice in the regexp

```js
const body = "$foo$bar$baz$foo$bar$baz$wtf";
const result = body.match(/\$[^$]*\$/g).map(s => s.replace(/\$/g, ''));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice, I was thinking it would have to do with match $ followed by non-$ just as you have except I was forgetting the global flag, it's on by default in regex101.  I think this makes a nice canonical Q/A because I wasn't finding anything quite on point when googling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex `/\$\w+\$/g` to get the expected output'

```js
let regex = /\$\w+\$/g;

let str = '$foo$bar$baz$foo$bar$baz$wtf';
let result = str.match(regex).map( item => item.replace(/\$/g, ''));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) in the regex.

```js
const str1 = '$foo$bar$baz$foo$bar$baz$wtf';
const regex1 = /\$(\w+)\$/g;

const str2 = '*foo*bar*baz*foo*bar*baz*wtf';
const regex2 = /\*(\w+)\*/g;

const find = (str, regex) =>
  new Array(str.match(regex).length)
  .fill(null)
  .map(m => regex.exec(str)[1]);

console.log('delimiters($)', JSON.stringify(find(str1, regex1)));
console.log('delimiters(*)', JSON.stringify(find(str2, regex2)));
```